# Python integer partitioning

Tags: python, numbers

I am trying to write a piece of code that will give me the partitions of a number.So far I came up with this(found on google).

```
def gen(n):
           # tuple version
           if n == 0:
               yield ()
               return

           for p in gen(n-1):
               yield (1, ) + p
               if p and (len(p)<2 or p[1] > p[0]):
                   yield (p[0] + 1, ) + p[1:]

print(list(gen(5)))
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand how this Recursive function works.Please help.Thank you.

Comment: What part are you confused about?

Comment: I would really love if you can please explain every single line please.That will help me understand better how yield works.Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Python yield keyword explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Comment: I've read that before and I did understand how yield work.But that doesn't answer my question.I still cannot understand why he wrote yield() then return and why he wrote yield(1,)+p.That's what confuses me.Could you please explain to me how this works.Thank you.

Comment: 1) All generators have to `return` after they have `yield`ed their final result. Usually the return is implicit when they fall off the bottom of the function. (Contemplate [this program](http://ideone.com/MYAHC2)) 2) `yield (1,)+p` is part of his recursive algorithm. That expression creates a tuple with `1` as the initial element and the members of `p` as the remaining elements. So if, for example, `(2,2)` is a partition of the number 4, then `(1,2,2)` is a partition of the number 5.

Comment: Because you can add tuples in Python: `(3,)+(1,)==(3,1)` and `()+(3,)==(3,)` and `if n==0: yield (); return` breaks recursion...

Answer (score 3):

To understand what's going on, it helps to print the output of the generator for several sequentially increasing values of `n`:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
        print(list(gen(i)))

[()]
[(1,)]
[(1, 1), (2,)]
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 2), (3,)]
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 3), (4,)]
```

The computation of each sequence is based on the one before it. Here's a line-by line explanation of how it works:

```
if n == 0:
    yield ()
    return
```

These first few lines of the generator are for the base case, where `n` is zero. The `return` statement makes it exit after yielding an empty tuple, rather than continuing on with the rest of the code.

```
for p in gen(n-1):
```

This is the recursive step of the function. Since `gen` is a generator, it's done with a loop, so the rest of the code will run repeatedly with `p` taking different values from the results of the recursion.

```
    yield (1, ) + p
```

This is an important line. What this does is yield out of the generator a new tuple formed by concatenating a `1` onto the front of the value `p`. If `p` was the empty tuple, this will be a 1-tuple. If `p` already had some values, the tuple will become longer.

```
    if p and (len(p)<2 or p[1] > p[0]):
```

This is a complicated condition. The second check, `len(p)<2` could really be written `len(p)==1`, since the `p and` part at the start has already ruled out `p` being empty.

There are two kinds of values that `p` can have, in order to pass. Either `p` has exactly one value, or it has more values, and its first value is less than its second value. So `(3,)` will pass, as will `(1,2)`, but `(1,1,1)` will not.

```
        yield (p[0] + 1, ) + p[1:]
```

This is another tuple concatenation. It's increasing the first value of `p` by one and then concatenating it with the rest of `p` (using a slice). So `(3,)` will become `(4,)` (with the slice being empty), `(1,2)` becomes `(2,2)`, etc.

So, now lets run through the results we saw above.

```
[()]
```

With `n` equal to 0, the base case is hit and you get a single empty tuple yielded.

```
[(1,)]
```

With `n` equal to 1, the loop runs one time, and concatenates `(1,)` onto the empty tuple, yielding the 1-tuple `(1,)`. The first part of the `if` condition is not passed, since `p` is empty.

```
[(1,1), (2,)]
```

With `n` equal to 2, the loop still only runs once. First it yields `(1,1)` by concatenating `(1,)` with itself to get `(1,1)`. But this time, the `if` block is run because `p` had just a single value. So it also yields `(p[0]+1,) + p[1:]`. The slice part of that is the empty tuple, but the first part is `(2,)`.

```
[(1,1,1), (1,2), (3,)]
```

Now finally the loop gets to run more than once! The first time though, it concatenates another `(1,)` onto the front of `(1,1)`, and since the `if` statement's conditions are not met, that's all it does. On the second pass however, it yields two values, once concatenating `(1,)` and `(2,)` and then incrementing `(2,)` to `(3,)`.

```
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 3), (4,)]
```

This one I'll leave to you, to walk through. Like the cases above, `p` will take on each of the values from the previous level of call (`(1,1,1), (1,2), (3,)`) and for each value it will yield either one or two new results.

Comment: I really appreciate what you have wrote and thank you for taking the time writing all of this.It helped me a lot and I hope it helps other people too.

Comment: @SerjCodito If this answer helped you, and you feel it answered your question adequately you should accept it(and possibly upvote)

Answer (score 0):

[`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) turns your function into a generator. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) for a good explanation.

Basically, instead of creating a list of results at once and then returning it:

```
def f():
    output = []

    for i in range(10):
        output.append(i + 3)

    return output
```

You can create a generator that `yield`s items only when you request one:

```
def f():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i + 3
```

It's also possible to make infinite generators:

```
def f():
    a = 0
    b = 1

    while True:
        yield b

        a, b = b, a + b
```

Iterating over `f()` will just keep spitting out terms of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Thank you,but I already know what you've wrote.Thing is that I don't understand why he wrote yield() then return and why how this -> yield (1, ) + p works.Can you please explain